# What are the databases Installed by Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0.2?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sql-database

My motive behind asking this is, trying to understand the roles and responsibilities of each databases and differentiate them from the other database(Sitecore Experience Platform).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore Commerce 9 has 2 databases:

The **Global database** – stores all the global configuration data (policies and environments) that govern how the engine roles function.

The **Shared Environments database** – the main data store for a commerce deployment. It stores all of the commerce data used on site, including catalog data, customer records, pricing information, and any promotions you have configured, along with the generic entities and lists that power the functionality created in the various installed plugins.

On bellow picture you can see all databases,roles and indexes which are used in Commerce 9. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the details. I do not see any database as "SXAStorefrontSite_profiles" but this database details can be found in many Json files as in "\CommerceAuthoring_Sc9\wwwroot\data\Environments\PlugIn.AdventureWorks.CommerceAuthoring-1.0.0.json"

Comment: That is used by the Commerce Server Migration plugin, the SXAStorefrontSite_profiles database you refer to is the old Profiles database from Commerce Server, this plugin reads the data from that database and moves them into the XC9 format, storing them in the SharedEnvironments Database

Answer (score 0):

There are two Databases which gets installed  on installing Sitecore commerce 9

1. Global DataBase : It Stores all the Global configuration data of Sitecore commerce Engine . Any Customization that needs to be done apart from generic commerce engine has to be done here.

Global configuration data can be Policies or environment
A policy is a group of settings that define and affect the functionality of the individual features or plugins in the commerce engine.

Policies are named, versionable, variable datasets that help make the engine flexible and configurable. They are stored in the policy store in the Global database and are heavily cached.

An environment in Sitecore XC is a collection of policies that affect how a call to the engine is handled. In other words, when a storefront calls the commerce engine for any functionality, it identifies the appropriate environment, which in turn effects the functionality provided by the engine.

2.Shared Environment :
 It stores all of the commerce data which you create in commerce like your catalog , inventory , price Card, Promotions , customer details , order Details